# closure implementing FnMut not working on place where dyn FnMut is expected

Tags: rust

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;
use wasm_bindgen::JsCast;

fn main() {
    let closure_cell = Rc::new(RefCell::new(None));
    let closure_cell_clone = Rc::clone(&closure_cell);
    *closure_cell.borrow_mut() = Some(Closure::wrap(Box::new(move || {
        request_animation_frame(closure_cell_clone.borrow().as_ref().unwrap());
    })));
}
fn request_animation_frame(f: &Closure<dyn FnMut()>) {
}
```

In the above code `request_animation_frame` expects `&Closure<dyn FnMut()>`and I pass a `closure` which implements `FnMnut`. But I am getting an error

```
expected type `std::option::Option<wasm_bindgen::closure::Closure<dyn std::ops::FnMut()>>`
found type `std::option::Option<wasm_bindgen::closure::Closure<[closure@src/lib.rs:29:62: 39:6 bucket:_, world:_, closure_cell_clone:_]>>`
```

Arent `FnMut` default implemented if  a closure can implement that trait? Cant a closure which implements `FnMut` be sent in place of `dyn FnMut` ? What am I missing here?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a pretty sneaky problem. Here's why:

While you can coerce a `Box<T>` to a `Box<dyn Trait>` if `T: Trait`, those two are incompatible types, in that you cannot use a variable or field of the type `Box<T>` as a `Box<dyn Trait>`.

Here's an example to show why that could lead to undefined behaviour, using `Cell<...>`s (where that box would be a field somewhere in `Cell<...>`)

```rust
use std::cell::Cell;

trait SomeTrait { }

#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub struct A;

impl SomeTrait for A { }

#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub struct B;

impl SomeTrait for B { }

fn use_coerced(cell: &Cell<Box<dyn SomeTrait>>) {
    cell.set(Box::new(B));  // valid, since `B` implements `SomeTrait`
}

fn main() {
    // I'll put what the type inference will come up with as explicit types here
    let some_cell: Cell<Box<A>> = Cell::new(Box::new(A));
    use_coerced(&some_cell);  // If cells would coerce, this would be valid
    let value: Box<A> = some_cell.into_inner();  // But we put `Box<B>` in there. So we'd have undefined behaviour.
}
```

So to solve that problem, you have to tell the compiler to use the `dyn FnMut()` type instead of the closure type somewhere. I personally prefer explicitely unsizing it after creating the `Box`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let closure_cell = Rc::new(RefCell::new(None));
    let closure_cell_clone = Rc::clone(&closure_cell);
    *closure_cell.borrow_mut() = Some(Closure::wrap(Box::new(move || {
        request_animation_frame(closure_cell_clone.borrow().as_ref().unwrap());
    }) as Box<dyn FnMut()>));
}

fn request_animation_frame(f: &Closure<dyn FnMut()>) { }
```

You can, however, also specify the type of the cell:

```rust
fn main() {
    let closure_cell: Rc<RefCell<Option<Closure<dyn FnMut()>>>> = Rc::new(RefCell::new(None));
    let closure_cell_clone = Rc::clone(&closure_cell);
    *closure_cell.borrow_mut() = Some(Closure::wrap(Box::new(move || {
        request_animation_frame(closure_cell_clone.borrow().as_ref().unwrap());
    })));
}

fn request_animation_frame(f: &Closure<dyn FnMut()>) { }
```

But that is, as you can see, way more wordy, and unnecessarily so.

Comment: I still do not understand why the coercion doesnt happen and why each closure is  a different type matters. The closure implicitly implements `FnMut` if i am right. So the coercion shouldnt happen shouldnt it? Another example without closure that works without `as` here https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8c537d11cbe74dacde97aadf33f969d4

Comment: @raj I've updated the answer to be a whole lot more explaining and just *better*.

Comment: but in this the coercion would have happened if the `funcion` signature was `fn use_coerced(cell: Cell<Box<dyn SomeTrait>>) {` . If the function accepts `Cell` instead of reference it would coerce.

Comment: @raj Yeah, because in this case it's safe, because you cannot get the original type back anyway. But honestly, that feels a little besides the point, since that's just miles away from your original question. The answer to that was "help Rusts type inference".